# Custom 404 page for Spring RsourceHandler

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a Spring/Tiles 3 application with a custom 404 page. This works fine for everything but static resources.

The configuration:

```
public class WebApplication implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext ctx) throws ServletException         {
    final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webCtx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    webCtx.register(GlobalExceptionHandler.class,...);
    webCtx.setServletContext(ctx);
    final DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(webCtx);
    dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
```

The global exception handler, pointing to the right tiles view

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ModelAndView handle(final NoHandlerFoundException exception) {
        return new ModelAndView("exceptions/NotFoundException");
    }
...
```

This works fine.

However, I also have some static resources

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/images/");
}
```

The resources are server fine, but when I try to access a resource that doesn't exist, I get the default 404 page from the applicationserver. How do I tell spring to use the GlobalExceptionHandler  for static resources?